# Project Name appearing wrong in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, filenames

I took a coding course online and wanted to re-do my project to my own needs so I decided to copy the project files and amend / start anew what I needed. However in my IDE (PhpStorm) I still see the old name in brackets:

[image: how name appears in IDE]

Can anyone please let me know from where I can amend it?

Answer (score 12):

Right click on it and choose `Refactor | Rename`. Then choose `Rename project` in appeared popup. You can also use `File | Rename Project...` instead.

Alternatively, try deleting/editing `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea/.name` file (it's a plain text file with a single line of text). The IDE must be closed at that time of course (otherwise it will overwrite it with the current data when you close the project).

---

Other than that (if the above does not work for some strange reason): delete the whole `.idea` subfolder and create a new project from existing files (you would need to configure project from scratch though).